# Regex: All-Purpose Tag Stripper?

Tags: regex

My question may have been asked and answered in other discussions - which I've been browsing through, though I haven't yet found the exact answer.

I need to do some search-and-replace operations on a large number of files, using Dreamweaver, TextWrangler or a similar program. (I'm working on a Mac, by the way.) My immediate goal is to find a regex that removes this...

```
<span class="pfirst">
```

and the following closing tag...

```
</span>
```

but leaves everything in between. Thus, this...

```
<span class="pfirst">We won!</span>
```

Would be converted to this:

```
We won!
```

But I'd also like to know if anyone out there has put together an all-purpose regex that does the same thing but which can be easily modified to work on 1) specific tags, and/or 2) tags with specific classes or ID's.

For example, you could instruct the regex to match only paragraph tags or only table tags - or only table tags with the ID "MyTable".

I've been Googling various tag stripping pages and have found lots of scripts that are supposed to do pretty much what I've described. However, the ones I've tried so far don't work (for me), or I haven't yet figured out how to modify them to target only span tags with the class "pfirst."

Also, it appears that Dreamweaver and TextWrangler use different regex syntax, so maybe I need to find a different text editor?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use replace. So you match the opening and closing tags and the text within them and then you replace by just the text. Here is an example:

`<[^>]*.(.*)<[^>]*.`

and then replace by the match by the group `\1` which was what the text matched between the tags.

Here is an example:

http://regex101.com/r/qY3aU1

You can see that it only matches the text in between since that is the only matching group. Then, replace the whole regex by the first group `\1`

I don't know about your language in specific but this is what it would look like in python:

```
>>> original_string = '<span class="pfirst">We won!</span>'
>>> new_string = re.sub(r'<[^>]*.(.*)<[^>]*.', r'\1', original_string)
>>> print new_string
We won!
```

Comment: Close - I tried <[^>]*.(.*)<[^>]*. in TextWrangler, and it did nothing, but when I tried it in Dreamweaver, it zapped the tags. Unfortunately, it deleted everything between the tags, too. However, it looks like you're matching not just the tag but the content - "We won!" In my examples, the span tags include a wide variety of content. So I'm trying to find a generic regex that simply zaps every instance of span class="pfirst" (and the closing tag), regardless of what lies between the tags.

Comment: @DavidBlomstrom, Please also see my python example at the end of my answer. I said that you should do a __replace__ by matching that regex  and then replacing it with group `\1`. Again, my python example. Hopefully you can customize it for your dreamweaver needs.

Comment: I'm not really sure how to adapt Python code to Dreamweaver or TextWrangler, but thanks.

Comment: @DavidBlomstrom. Is there a replace feature in Dreamweaver.

Comment: Yes, Dreamweaver has a search-and-replace feature - and you can choose between normal replace and regular expression. TextWrangler lets you choose between normal and something called Grep.

Comment: @DavidBlomstrom, Perfect. Dreamweaver replace regular expression option is what you want.

Comment: Yes, that's what I've been using.

Comment: I found a script that I think is supposed to do what I want -- $text1 = preg_replace("#<span.[^>]*?>.*?</span>#ism","",$text1); But I don't understand how to implement it. It looks like $text1 = the content between the tags - so yo have to know what that content is before you can use it.

Comment: @DavidBlomstrom. Did my implementation not work? What problems did it yield.

Comment: It just says "Not found."

Comment: @DavidBlomstrom, Interesting. As you can see on the demo I posted, it works correctly.

Comment: Oh, THAT code. Like I said earlier, I tried it in Dreamweaver, but it deletes EVERYTHING - all tags and everything in between. I need to refine it so that it only matches span tags with the class "pfirst" and so it only deletes the tags, not the text between the tags.

Comment: Yikes, I guess I get today's Dumbo award. I've been using Dreamweaver forever and didn't even know it had the very feature I'm describing built in! If you choose Edit > Find and Replace > Search, you can then choose between search documents via text or HTML mode. I never even noticed another option - "Specific Tag." I stumbled across it just now. Sheez, I wish I had known about it a decade ago; it would have saved me countless hours. ;(

Comment: @DavidBlomstrom. Haha that's happened to me lots of times. Hope I was atleast a bit of help. If my answer was helpful, would you mind accepting it? Thank you